# putting a link to a pdf and using pdf as the image

Tags: html

I have a webpage that has a magazine on it.  I have an img tag with a link to the pdf on the server.  When the magazine changes I have to upload a new magazine and upload a new image as a thumbnail for the magazine.  Is there a way to accomplish the same task by just uploading the pdf so that I don't have to create an image of the cover and then upload it also?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers support embedding PDF files natively, but not all do. It is not currently possible to do this unless you have a PDF to jpeg conversion script on your server that will generate the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

you can embed a pdf with an object element